# Escaping a complicated string with PHP

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
<form action='php/zoneNotifUnsub.php' id='zoneNotifUnsub' method='POST'>
    <?php
       echo $var;
    ?>
</form>
```

I want to echo it out with PHP, and have it look exactly as above.

I started with this:

```
echo '<form action='php/zoneNotifUnsub.php' id='zoneNotifUnsub' method='POST'>
    <?php
       echo $var;
    ?>
</form>';
```

But the additional single quotes inside are causing me problems. How can I have the exact verbatim output of my string print (so that no variables are parsed and no code is run)?

Answer (score 3):

Normal Escaping would look like this:

```
echo '<form action=\'php/zoneNotifUnsub.php\' id=\'zoneNotifUnsub\' method=\'POST\'>
    <?php
       echo $var;
    ?>
</form>';
```

Escaping every one of the `'` with a backslash. To recap [`how strings work look in the manual page`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

You could also go with the [`HEREDOC Syntax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) that would look a little bit nicer:

```
echo <<<OUT
<form action='php/zoneNotifUnsub.php' id='zoneNotifUnsub' method='POST'>
    <?php
       echo $var;
    ?>
</form>
OUT;
```

Comment: He's obviously a beginner at php, I think throwing HEREDOC at him is a bit much, although the answer is accurate.

Comment: +1 HEREDOC is fun to tinker with when you first discover it, but I've never seen a good use of/for it in my 6 years of php experience. Not arguing, just conversation. However, I don't see how having asked more questions makes you more capable of comprehending the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use double quotes for the things you want to echo.

So: `'<form action="php/zoneNotifUnsub.php" id="zoneNotifUnsub" method="POST">';` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping them

```
echo '<form action=\'php/zoneNotifUnsub.php\' id=\'zoneNotifUnsub\' method=\'POST\'>
    <?php
       echo $var;
    ?>
</form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using double quotes could be an option in this case:

```
echo "<form action='php/zoneNotifUnsub.php' id='zoneNotifUnsub' method='POST'>
    <?php
       echo $var;
    ?>
</form>";
```